# Difference between potential and potential energy in physics?

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, potential-energy, voltage, definition

Title says it all.

What exactly is the difference between [potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential) and [potential energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy) in conservative force field  like gravity or electric force field. I am getting confused between the two especially in definition, significance  and application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electric potential is electric energy per charge. If a charge $q$ has potential energy $U$, then that means that the electric potential at that point is $V=U/q$.

For gravity, replace "charge" with "mass".

Comment: But what is significance of adding the term 'potential'?

Comment: It means that it is not kinetic energy, but has the potential to be converted into kinetic energy.

Comment: It may help if you think of potential energy as stored energy.